# Image stitch of DJI Mavic mini 2 panoramas programmatically

Tags: python, opencv, dji-sdk

I used dji fly app to create panoroma image taken by dji mini 2 drone. My aim is to automate this process either server side or create an app to make panoroma.
I tried to **write code for creating panorama image** out of 26 images taken by **dji mini 2 drones**. I have gone through [DJI SDK](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/PanoDemo.html) and sample code on [android](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-PanoramaDemo) and [ios](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/iOS-PanoramaDemo) as well since these are too old they did not updated it (android app is not even campatible with modern code structre). I tried **open cv python** and failed miserably as it took too long to create a single  image(some image output were wrong also). I have seen the DJI fly app working great and someone tell me how  can I achieve that.
I am open to all suggestions don't limit yourself to android devices.

My open cv code:

```
# grab the paths to the input images and initialize our images list
print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images("/content/drive/MyDrive/100_0040")))
images = []
# loop over the image paths, load each one, and add them to our
# images to stitch list
print(imagePaths)
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    images.append(image)
print("[INFO] stitching images...")
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher() if imutils.is_cv3() else cv2.Stitcher_create()
(status, stitched) = stitcher.stitch(images)
print(status)
# if the status is '0', then OpenCV successfully performed image
# stitching
if status == 0:
    # write the output stitched image to disk
    cv2.imwrite('/content/sample_data/output11.jpeg', stitched)
    # display the output stitched image to our screen
    cv2.imshow("Stitched", stitched)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
# otherwise the stitching failed, likely due to not enough keypoints)
# being detected
else:
    print("[INFO] image stitching failed ({})".format(status))
```

creates image but with black spots in between.

Comment: There is a use case for drones in my stitching python package: https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching/issues/28.

Comment: @LukasWeber - would it be able to take the 26 images from DJI drones and turn them into a single equirectangular 360-degree panorama photo?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update, I used open CV but could not succeed, then emailed DJI for their solution with their SDK, but they were reluctant to update their SDK for entry-level drones. I used video frames to stitch images(consecutive images must have a common edge ) and the results were satisfactory for my work. though it's not the complete 360 sphere that I wanted. I am open to suggestions.